# Is it possible to run a discord bot comand from a website

Tags: javascript, php, discord, discord.js, bots

So I want to have a system, where when a certain action occurs on the website, to open a support ticket on the discord server automatically. I can use any discord ticket bot that would work. I tried to use webhooks with php and try to get a bot to send the command to open a ticket but I found out that discord bots can't run other discord bot commands. What should my plan of action be?

Right now I'm using this ticket bot that runs off node.js and uses discord.js

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be an existing ticket bot which you have no control over?

Comment: @user15517071 it doesn't have to be. For example. i could use any ticket bot or create my own if thats whats required. or one off github where i have the source code for to modify

Comment: This is actually pretty simple, assuming you are running your *own* ticket bot. You just need to run your website and your discord bot on NodeJS http servers (optimally the same server, but not mandatory) and take advantage of GET/POST requests to send info from webpage to server (e.g. your webpage submits a form via POST to your-bot.com/api/tickets/open, and your bot server then gets the form data from that request and uses it to create a ticket). You could use [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) to quickly setup some http request handlers in this way.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Cannicide/panacea/blob/master/website.js) is an example of using the http request method, from one of my own bots. I use GET requests and URL query parameters to get data from the URL (example: your-bot.com/api/tickets/open?name=Ticket+Name&author=Cannicide)

Comment: @Cannicide so is that file in ur bot files or website files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little vague so I'll try my best to answer it.

## If this is your bot.

Run an express server in the same app as your Discord Bot that listens for you to POST a Ticket. You can learn more about express here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

// Your discord.js BOT code.

const express = require('express');
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/ticket', async (request, response) => {
  // console.log(request.body);      // the information in your POST request's body
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('guild_id');
  guild.channels.create(request.body.ticketName);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This was a quick mockup and can be implemented in many ways, once you learn express you can find a way that fits your needs.

## If this is NOT your bot.

Unless the bot has an API or allows bots to use its commands, you CANNOT do this without the use of a self-bot. (Not recommended: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a proposal but is implemented in python

```py
from server import app
from bot import bot
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import multiprocessing
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

env_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/.env"
load_dotenv(env_path)

def start_server():
    app.run()

def start_bot():
    token = os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN")
    bot.run(token)

def start_multiprocess():
    bot_thread = multiprocessing.Process(name="bot_thread", target=start_bot)
    server_thread = multiprocessing.Process(name="server_thread", target=start_server)
    bot_thread.start()
    server_thread.start()

def run():
    start_multiprocess()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Assume that app is just your average Flask app and bot your regular instance of `commands.Bot`.

If you run this will work (a web server and discord but running as expected independently) but have certain flaws such as the process cannot communicate with each other, in other words, you cannot use functions or variables of the bot from the server. To address those limitations you will have to look further into the concurrency packages of python such as `asyincio`